# mysql insert value in column : int DEFAULT 0 causing error

Tags: mysql

I am not able to find out what is the exact issue. When I remove index param from below mentioned query and try to insert the data it works fine, but trying to add index cause an error.
Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `address_list` (
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `currency_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `index` int DEFAULT 0,
  `address_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `balance` varchar(500) DEFAULT "0.0",
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

and here is my insert query :

```
insert into address_list (email,currency_name,address,label,index,address_type) Values ('abc@gmail.com','bitcoin','mgbtUQt7ppCEhxWmvicxrbEDYSom5kNk8X','test address',3,'wallet');
```

error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index) Values ('abc@gmail.com','bitcoin','mgbtUQt7ppCEhxWmvicxrbEDYSom5kNk8X'' at line 1
```

Comment: `index` is a reserved word, it needs to be quoted. Voting to close this question as a typo.

Comment: @GMB how is that a typo?  surely it would be better to find an appropriate question to mark this a duplicate of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` is a reserved word in mysql; rename your column to something else, or else place it in backticks where you want to use it:

```
insert into address_list (email,currency_name,address,label,`index`,address_type) Values ('abc@gmail.com','bitcoin','mgbtUQt7ppCEhxWmvicxrbEDYSom5kNk8X','test address',3,'wallet');
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html